# CSS file not included when using php include

Tags: php, css, web, php-include

I have a css file called main.css in my styles folder on the root of my project:

```
#header
{
    background-color: aqua;
    height: 120px;
}
```

In another php file header.php I have something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/main.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<header id="header"></header>
```

I also have a footer.php:

```
</body>
</html>
```

When combining the in my index.php like this:

```
<?php
    require('includes/header.php');
?>
<?php
    require('includes/footer.php');
?>
```

the result is that my css rules don't get applied. How can I fix this?

Comment: Is the styles folder within the includes folder? If not, if they both have the same parent directory, change the CSS path to ../styles/main.css

Comment: I did, and the result was the same. It only loads in header.php, not in index.php.

Comment: How do you access your project in the browser? Is it located in a subfolder like `http://localhost/myproject/index.php`?

Comment: Yes, it is exactly like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem may be in your css path if php file and style folder both are in root use like this href="styles/main.css"

Answer (score 1):

Link your css file using base

try

```
href="../styles/main.css"
```

Comment: But the path I use is absolute.

Comment: This only works when accessing header.php. When loading index.php, it fails.

Answer (score 1):

it seems like your css file path cause this problem.

if your directory structure like this below:

- includes
- |__header.php
- |__footer.php
- styles
- |__main.css

replace the css path in the header.php like:

href="../styles/main.css"